# Transform AWS S3 Object into ByteString issue

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka

I'm working on a process of upload files from S3 to Facebook using Akka. According to Facebook API docs, files should be uploaded via small parts - chunks. Based on a file size, Facebook gives you an information about bytes offset which it expects to receive in a next request.

Firstly I make a `GetObjectRequest` to S3 via Java AWS SDK, in order to receive a chunk with a required bytes size:

```scala
val objChunkReq = new GetObjectRequest(get.s3ObjId.bucketName, get.s3ObjId.key)
  objChunkReq.setRange(get.fbUploadSession.from, get.fbUploadSession.to)

  Try(s3Client.getObject(objChunkReq)) match {
    case Success(s3ObjChunk) => Right(S3ObjChunk(s3ObjChunk, get.fbUploadSession))
    case Failure(ex) => Left(S3Exception(ex.getMessage))
  }
```

Then in case if the S3 response is successful, I can work with the received chunk as with an `InputStream` in order to pass it then into Facebook HTTP request:

```scala
private def inputStreamToArrayByte(is: InputStream) = {
  Try {
    val reads: Int = is.read()
    val byteStringBuilder = ByteString.newBuilder
    while (is.read() != -1) {
      byteStringBuilder.asOutputStream.write(reads)
      is.read()
    }
    is.close()
    byteStringBuilder.result()
  }
}
```

The issue I faced is that size of `s3ObjChunk` from the first code snippet has twice bigger size in bytes than the resulting `ByteString` from the second one code snippet.

`s3ObjChunk.getObjectMetadata.getContentLength == n`

`byteStringBuilder.result().length == n / 2`

I have two assumptions: 
a) I transform the `InputStream` into `ByteString` incorrectly 
b) The `ByteString` compresses the `InputStream`

How to transform an S3 object `InputStream` into a `ByteString` correctly?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/zengularity/benji

Comment: It's an extra lib which should be involved :( I'd better to try something with native Scala or Akka solution. But any way, thanks :)

Comment: Using AWS lib is already an extra lib, on the other side Benji is based on Akka stream, so reactive by nature and Scala idiomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `n` vs `n / 2` in the resulting output may be explained by a bug in the implementation.

`is.read()` is called twice in the loop, and none of its returns is indeed written into the output stream, but only the first one, stored in `val reads`.

The implementation should change to something like:

```
val byteStringBuilder = ByteString.newBuilder
val output = byteStringBuilder.asOutputStream
try {
  var reads: Int = is.read() // note "var" instead of "val"
  while (reads != -1) {
    output.write(reads)
    reads = is.read()
  }
} finally {
  is.close() // should it be here or closed by the caller?
  // also close "output"
}
byteStringBuilder.result()
```

Or, another approach would be to use slightly more idiomatic stream reading with `scala.io.Source`, for example:

```
val byteStringBuilder = ByteString.newBuilder
val output = byteStringBuilder.asOutputStream
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).foreach(output.write(_))
byteStringBuilder.result()
```

Comment: Big thanks for the hint about the possible bug. I'll try both of your suggestions tomorrow and reply on the comment once again!